# How to write solution file for an LP problem with Coin-or Cbc Solver?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, coin-or-cbc, coin-or

I use the C++ library of COIN-OR Cbc Solver to solve some LP problems. And I can't find anywhere a function or something that writes the solution file. I think somewhere in the code there is this functionality because you can use COIN-OR's command line interface to write the solution as a file ( cbc problem.lp solve -solu solution.txt ), however it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

If I run on command line

```
cbc problem.lp
```

The problem gets solved and I get the optimal solution.

If I run

```
cbc problem.lp solve -solu solution.txt
```

I get this error - Unable to open file .\solve -

Comment: I think it is `-solve`.

Comment: You are right! It worked with cbc problem.lp -solve -solu solution.txt